# Browser won't show the crystal report on IIS 8 local web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I'm trying to publish a simple Crystal Report on IIS 8 local web server using Visual Studio 2012 IDE. The site works fine in VS but after publishing whenever I try to browse it using IIS web sever it gives nothing on the browser.

I've tried changing the ports, changing web config code(listed below), installed everything in the IIS services but nothing works. The provided IIS services 'Error Pages' and 'Failed Request Tracing' are empty.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
  <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
    <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null"/>
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<appSettings>
<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true"/>
<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000"/>
<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000"/>
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine,   Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
  </assemblies>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rpt"  type="CrystalDecisions.Web.Compilation.RptBuildProvider, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<businessObjects>
<crystalReports>
  <rptBuildProvider>
    <add embedRptInResource="true"/>
  </rptBuildProvider>
</crystalReports>
</businessObjects>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
</handlers>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to find the problem, and then try working on it.

1. In web config enable Debug log, so that you can get the error.   , Make sure you disable it once your problem is solved
2. Check Event Logs Start > Run > eventvwr > Custom Views > Server Roles > Web Server & Other Application Errors
3. Do check whether your Web App is 32 bit or 64 bit, Uninstall CR driver and Install it again.

   Reference:

32 bit : http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_19.zip

64 bit: http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_19.zip

Hope this helps you!